# Matomo - On Premise - Create Custom Report to See Page Views for a given timeframe

Tags: report, matomo

We have the On-Premise setup of Matomo. Can someone let me know how we can generate reports with :

1. **A graph having Pageviews by hour, total pageviews, and then**
2. **Top pages of the day and their pageviews at the bottom.**

Look forward to your responses. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried customising your dashboard and adding widgets to it? https://matomo.org/docs/dashboards/